# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mapbox_key'

Tags: python, mapping, pydeck

everyone !
I'm trying to understand how to make maps with PyDeck, but i have a recurring error message : " TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mapbox_key'".

After hours, I don't know how to resolve it ? have you any idea ?

code :

```
Python 3.9.12
version de Pydeck :  0.8.0
version de pandas:  1.4.2
version de vega_datasets :  0.9.0
version de ipywidgets : 7.6.5
```

```
import pydeck as pdk
import pandas as pd
from vega_datasets import data as vds
import ipywidgets
from palettable.cartocolors.sequential import BrwnYl_3
import json

# Public API key
MAPBOX_API_KEY = "pk.eyJ1IjoiZXphYW45MDIiLCJhIjoiY2xhdHI4NzI3MDQwazNwcDg1bDdyN3ZzMCJ9.8BOAE-IFmp6PeellMppXsA"

# data
data = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/groundhogday321/dataframe-datasets/master/fake_commute_data.csv'
commute_pattern = pd.read_csv(data)
print(commute_pattern.head(2))

# view (location, zoom level, etc.)
view = pdk.ViewState(latitude=32.800382, longitude=-97.040728, pitch=50, zoom=9)

# layer
# from home (orange) to work (purple)
arc_layer = pdk.Layer('ArcLayer',
                      data=commute_pattern,
                      get_source_position=['from_lon', 'from_lat'],
                      get_target_position=['to_lon', 'to_lat'],
                      get_width=5,
                      get_tilt=15,
                      # RGBA colors (red, green, blue, alpha)
                      get_source_color=[255, 165, 0, 80],
                      get_target_color=[128, 0, 128, 80])

# render map

arc_layer_map = pdk.Deck(map_style='mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
                         layers=arc_layer,
                         initial_view_state=view,
                         mapbox_key=MAPBOX_API_KEY)

# display and save map (to_html(), show())
arc_layer_map.to_html(r'C:\Users\Admin loc\OneDrive\Bureau\arc_layer_map.html')
arc_layer_map.show()
```

I tried to load my Mapbox token and run this tutorial...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://pydeck.gl/deck.html) `pdk.Deck` doesn't take a `mapbox_key` argument.
You probably need to provide it like this:

```py
arc_layer_map = pdk.Deck(...
                         api_keys={'mapbox': MAPBOX_API_KEY})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, your advice work,. But only the flow is displayed., the basemap tile is missing. Have you any other idea?